# Create custom tag for validator in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, custom-tag

I have created a custom validator for my JSF project. I can use it like this:

```
<h:inputText id="inpUsername" value="#{testbean.value}">
    <f:validator validatorId="validators.TestValidator" />
</h:inputText>
```

I need to create a custom tag for it, so I can use it like this:

```
<h:inputText id="inpUsername" value="#{testbean.value}">
    <validators:myValidator />
</h:inputText>
```

How can I create a custom tag for my validator?
I am using Eclipse, JSF 2.0 and Glassfish

Answer (score 0):

You should create a tag in your `taglib.xml`

```
<tag>
  <tag-name>myValidator</tag-name>
  <validator>
    <validator-id>validators.TestValidator</validator-id>
  </validator>
</tag>
```

See http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#taglib-create-validator

About taglib.xml: http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#taglib-web

Answer (score 0):

for this need to follow the steps:

1. Write your custom tag in as a xhtml file
2. Create taglib.xml file and add an entry for your custom tag /validator

   ```
   <facelet-taglib>  
       <namespace>http://anyurl.com/unique</namespace>  
       <tag>  
         <tag-name>myTag</tag-name>  
         <source>tags/com/portal/myTag.xhtml</source>  
       </tag>  
       <tag>
         <tag-name>myValidator</tag-name>
         <validator>
            <validator-id>validators.TestValidator</validator-id>
         </validator>
       </tag
   </facelet-taglib>
   ```
3. Register in web.xml

   ```
    <context-param>
       <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
   ```
4. Use your custom tag by including the taglib